# What team comp beats a heal poke team?

Tags: league-of-legends

The heal poke meta was a very strong team comp because it allowed teams to push towers very effectively as well as slowly knocking down the enemies HP. Usually it consisted of 2 healers like nidalee / soraka or taric and with a strong ad and ap carry. I always found that comp to be very strong and effective.

So my question is what is an effective team comp to combat this?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the best way to handle it would be a strong initiate team. For example Galio, Ashe, Nocturne etc all have extremely good initiations that can really help to focus down 1 person quickly. That would be the key to beating them, isolating one of them and turning it into a 4v5 as quickly as possible to swing things in your favor.

Answer (score 0):

Very Tanky, with poke as well. Most likely a combination Lee Sin, Nautilus, Sion, Morde, Nunu, or Galio would be effective.